# Adding a hard and soft upper bound constraint of number of locations to visit (VRP)

Tags: python, or-tools

I went through the [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp) example and was able to replicate it. On the example, there is a constraint added for vehicle maximum distance as shown below:

```python
dimension_name = 'Distance'
routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,
    0,  # no slack
    3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    dimension_name)
distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
```

Similar to the [CVRP](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp), how do I modify the constraint for the number of locations that each vehicle can visit (either global or by each vehicle) rather than the demand?

Thanks!

Edit: Refer to [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4137/adding-a-hard-and-soft-upper-bound-constraint-of-number-of-locations-to-visit-v) for the answer.

Comment: I would highly suggest posting this question on https://or.stackexchange.com/  It is still a small community started about an year or so ago, but has a lot of OR experts. I am sure there would be people here that can help too, but having all OR questions on a single community would help others in future as well

Comment: Just posted the question [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4137/adding-a-hard-and-soft-upper-bound-constraint-of-number-of-locations-to-visit-v). Thanks!